# Better way to ask user input in integer form in Python?

Tags: python, loops, input

So I'm kind of very beginner to programming and just learning yet the basics. Now I would like to have my python program to ask the user to give a number and keep asking with a loop if string or something else is given instead.

So this is the best I came out with:

```
value = False
while value == False:
    a = input("Give a number: ")
    b = 0
    c = b
    try:
        int(a)
    except ValueError:
        print("No way")
        b += 1
    if c == b:
        value = True
```

So is there easier and better way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is a better way, but if you are as much of a beginner as you say you are, good job on thinking it through and doing something that made sense in your head to get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
while True:
    try:
        a = int(input("Give a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("No way")
```

or this:

```
while True:
    a = input("Give a number: ")
    if a.isdigit():
        break
    print("No way")
```

Comment: i think OP asks for keeping the loop running if the answer is not valid

Comment: @PRMoureu, yes, my mistake. But it has no sense

Comment: it's just to make the user input a valid number

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    try:
        a = int(input("Give a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("No way")
        continue
```

This will continue to prompt the user for an integer till they give one.

Comment: (the last `continue` is not needed if there is no code after)

Comment: The continue makes it loop, not continue to the end

Comment: Otherwise it would keep going once they gave an integer

Answer (score 0):

```
value = True
while value == True:
     a = input("Give a number: ")
     try:
        int(a)
     except ValueError:
        print("No way")
        continue
     print("Yay a Number:", a)
     value = False
```

Is this what you need?